# Forçar um atalho abrir o Firefox direto em uma página

Tags: windows, navegador-de-internet

Meu sistema é um gerenciador de obrigações fiscais e funciona em qualquer navegador praticamente, mas não testei em tudo, então não sei se vai ser estável em todos, eu desenvolvi fazendo testes no `firefox-dev`, então no Firefox é tudo 100% como deve ser.

É intranet, então não preciso de portabilidade. O que eu estou tentando é um `.bat` ou um atalho em que eu possa forçar abrir o Firefox direto no destino para o *login*.

Bom, só com atalho normal, bem simples, ele abre na URL, mas não estou conseguindo forçar com que abra o Firefox, ele sempre abre no navegador definido como padrão naquele computador.

Isso seria pra Windows 7, para os PCs com distros Linux eu consegui fazer tranquilo.

Não consegui fazer nada de exemplo, porque foi tudo via interface o que eu tentei fazer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar as duas formas:

1) Com atalho:

Ao criar um atalho, coloque `Unidade:/caminho/para/firefox.exe "www.endereco.do.site"`

2) Com linha de comando (possível de usar no batch também):

Conter a linha `Unidade:/caminho/para/firefox.exe www.endereco.do.site`
(Notar o espaço entre o caminho do Firefox e o endereço, sem usar aspas).

Se precisar de mais informações:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options

Comment: Tinha passado raspando kkk O primeiro deu certo ja, bem simples.